# BackgroundTask disables when in AirplaneMode (and does not enable itself afterwards)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have developed two applications and they are both using a background agent. When I turned on Airplane Mode last night, and woke up tomorrow I saw (Settings > Background Tasks) that 1 Background Task was running fine, and the other was not.

The one that was disabled gets data from a Weather API, and the other just generates random tiles (no internet connection).

When I opened the app, and went back to the Background Tasks it enabled itself.

What is going on here? I know that a background task will disable itself when the app is not used for 14(?) days, but this is not the case. And of course I know that the background task won't run when the phone is in Airplane Mode.

So, how can I enable my app to turn itself on again when the Airplane Mode is turned off? Just like my other (offline) app does.

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably means that your background task doesn't handle graciously no-connectivity errors. When your background agent fails two times in a row, it's automatically disabled by the OS.
Just put your network call in a try/catch block to solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Indeed, I have not try/catch-ed my network call. Will do so, and test it tonight :-)! Will update this topic accordingly tomorrow! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, KooKiz. I tested your suggestion last night, and my Background Task is still running :). Thanks!